# Converting year and day of year into datetime index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
 year  doy
 2000   49   
 2000   65   
 2000   81   
 2001   97   
 2001  113   
 2001  129   
 2001  145   
 2001  161
```

I want to create a datetime index for this dataframe. Here is what I am doing:

```
df.index = pandas.DatetimeIndex(df['doy'].apply(lambda x: date(2000, 1, 1)+ relativedelta(days=int(x)-1)))
```

However, this creates a datetime index which only uses 2000 as year. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [NumPy datetime64/timedelta64 arithmetic](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) to find the desired dates:

```
In [97]: (np.asarray(df['year'], dtype='datetime64[Y]')-1970)+(np.asarray(df['doy'], dtype='timedelta64[D]')-1)
Out[97]: 
array(['2000-02-18', '2000-03-05', '2000-03-21', '2001-04-07',
       '2001-04-23', '2001-05-09', '2001-05-25', '2001-06-10'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Since composing dates given various parts of dates (e.g. years, months, days, weeks, hours, etc.) is a common problem, here is a utility function to make it easier:

```
def compose_date(years, months=1, days=1, weeks=None, hours=None, minutes=None,
                 seconds=None, milliseconds=None, microseconds=None, nanoseconds=None):
    years = np.asarray(years) - 1970
    months = np.asarray(months) - 1
    days = np.asarray(days) - 1
    types = ('<M8[Y]', '<m8[M]', '<m8[D]', '<m8[W]', '<m8[h]',
             '<m8[m]', '<m8[s]', '<m8[ms]', '<m8[us]', '<m8[ns]')
    vals = (years, months, days, weeks, hours, minutes, seconds,
            milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds)
    return sum(np.asarray(v, dtype=t) for t, v in zip(types, vals)
               if v is not None)

df = pd.DataFrame({'doy': [49, 65, 81, 97, 113, 129, 145, 161],
                   'year': [2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001]})

df.index = compose_date(df['year'], days=df['doy'])
```

yields

```
            doy  year
2000-02-18   49  2000
2000-03-05   65  2000
2000-03-21   81  2000
2001-04-07   97  2001
2001-04-23  113  2001
2001-05-09  129  2001
2001-05-25  145  2001
2001-06-10  161  2001
```

Comment: `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` is the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Since `np.array([0], dtype='datetime64[Y]')` returns `array(['1970'], dtype='datetime64[Y]')`, we must subtract 1970.

Answer (score 33):

You can use the date specifier `%j` to extract the day of year. So combine the two columns, shift the year, and convert to datetime!

```
pd.to_datetime(df['year'] * 1000 + df['doy'], format='%Y%j')
```

returns

```
0   2000-02-18
1   2000-03-05
2   2000-03-21
3   2001-04-07
4   2001-04-23
5   2001-05-09
6   2001-05-25
7   2001-06-10
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: @AdamErickson http://strftime.org/ ... This site is extremely useful for python datetime format specifiers.

Answer (score 6):

In `pd.to_datetime()` you may specify the format and origin date as:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['doy'], unit='D', origin=pd.Timestamp(df['year']))
```

This method does all the hard work for you.

Comment: this is by far the best answer!

Comment: If you don't happen to have year in your dataframe you can also do `pd.to_datetime(df['doy'], unit='D', origin=pd.Timestamp(datetime(2001,1,1)))`

Answer (score 0):

## With `read_csv()`

```py
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

def yday2date(year, yday):
    return pd.to_datetime(year + '-' + yday,
                          format='%Y-%j')

df = pd.read_csv('input.txt', sep='\s+', 
                 parse_dates={'date': ['year', 'doy']},
                 date_parser=yday2date,
                 index_col='date')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Q: How to convert day of year to datetime?

#### A: Given arrays year and doy:

```
y = pd.to_datetime(year, format = '%Y')
td = pd.Series(doy).apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(x, unit = 'd'))
t =  y + td
```